# Chi-square goodness of fit test proof

Tags: statistics, chi-squared

I understand the classcial $\chi^2$ "goodness of fit" test used in Statistics, in which we compute $\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{(O_i - E_i)^2}{E_i}$ and, by comparing this quantity to a value found in a table of $\chi^2$ law (with a given risk $\alpha = 5\%$ for example), we decide if we should or not accept the hypothesis that the sample is likely to be an observation or not of a given distribution.

But I haven't found a good precise proof online yet, that shows that it's not only a good "recipe", but also has a strict proof, using probability theory (I know it exists, but I haven't found one yet).

**Do you know a good detailed proof?**

Comment: good find, @Basj

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think I finally found one [in this document](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-443-statistics-for-applications-fall-2006/lecture-notes/lecture11.pdf), page 2.

**Theorem** (Pearson): The random variable

$$\sum_{j=1}^n \frac{(\nu_j-n p_j)^2}{n p_j} \rightarrow \chi_{r-1}^2$$
converges in distribution to $\chi_{r-1}^2$-distribution with $r − 1$ degrees of freedom.

Comment: Thanks for the reference

Comment: Thanks, bro, your link is very useful!