# Why can a $\chi^2$ test be used to check whether a random variable has any distribution over a finite space?

Tags: probability, statistics, chi-squared

In particular, I see it used to test whether a random variable is Uniform even though the graph of the $\chi^2$ pdf doesn't ever seem to look much like a uniform distribution's pdf, and I don't understand why this is.

Comment: When you see it used for continuous random variables, are they binning the data?

Comment: Yes, Joe, the data is being binned, so I guess that turns the continuous into a pseudo-discrete (if that's even a term) random variable?

Comment: Actually, I think binning and using chi-square loses a lot of information, because (if I'm not mistaken) it treats each bin as independent.  Here's an answer on cross validated about it https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/166557/117192

Comment: Thanks for the link!

Comment: You're welcome. I'd always check cross validated for any stats question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll try to give an intuitive explanation rather than focus on the rigorous details, because those aren't too hard to find if you're interested.

First, an instructive example: consider a random variable $X$ that is uniformly distributed on $[0, 1]$. If you generate 100 copies of this random variable, how many of them will be less than $0.2$?

You're probably familiar with the binomial distribution, so you know it's relevant here; the number that land in that range will be binomially distributed with parameters $n = 100, p = 0.2$. If you run this experiment many times and plot the number of trials that land in that range, the number will be roughly bell-shaped with a peak around $20$. Even though there was nothing about the normal distribution in the problem, one appeared (essentially due to the magic of the Central Limit Theorem).

The $\chi^2$-distribution shows up in the application you mentioned for *extremely* similar reasons. So similar, in fact, that I'll start with the above description as a basis. Suppose you have $n$ data points, each of which can appear in $k$ different categories with various probabilities.

- Fix one of your categories. The number of the $n$ data points that appears in that category is binomially distributed; a binomial variable can be very well-approximated by a normal distribution.
- A normal distribution can be shifted and scaled to have the standard normal distribution.
- A squared standard normal distribution has a $\chi^2$-distribution.

The basic idea is to look at each category and measure something like the above, which should have a $\chi^2$ distribution. When you add indepenedent $\chi^2$ variables, you get a $\chi^2$-distribution with a higher degrees-of-freedom parameter. This gets complicated because the variables (which in this case are the *counts* of data points that land in each category) are indeed *dependent*, and this is why the degrees of freedom of the statistic is one *less* than the number of categories. However, it can be shown that the resulting statistic obtained by counting, shifting, scaling, squaring, and adding should indeed have an approximate $\chi^2$ distribution.

**EDIT:** To make this answer a bit more helpful since you asked for a reference for a rigorous proof: look at the theorem beginning at the bottom of page 2 [here](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/18-443-statistics-for-applications-fall-2006/resources/lecture11/).

Comment: So essentially $\chi^2$ shows up a lot because normal random variables show up a lot, so squared normal random variables do too?  Could you point me to a reference that has the more rigorous details.  The only stats book I have provides more breadth than depth.

Comment: Try this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2512481/chi-square-goodness-of-fit-test-proof

Comment: Thanks for the link and your helpful answer!